# T-SQL Parse text in select statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, select, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a project to import data from one table to another. I am trying to parse a field that contains a FULLNAME into its parts LAST,FIRST,MI. The names are all in the format of "LAST,FIRST MI" I have written a stored procedure that correctly parses and returns the results as neccessary but I am unsure as to how to encorporate the stored procedure into a single select statement. For instance, current I have:

```
SELECT FULLNAME From UserInfo
```

and what I would like to have is something like this:

```
SELECT Last, First, MI from UserInfo
```

Currently my stored procedure takes the form of ParseName(FULLNAME, Last as OUTPUT, First as OUTPUT, MI as OUTPUT). How can I call this procedure and have the output variables split into 3 different columns?

Comment: You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the database and have `FirstName`, `LastNName` and `MiddleInitial` fields instead of a `FULLNAME` one.

Comment: I am actually doing a Select INTO to import the data from the old table with FULLNAME into a table with FIRST, LAST, and MI columns. I am just trying to figure out how to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your stored procedure with [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can then apply this function to all the rows.

Below is an example - just put your logic for parsing the name

```
create FUNCTION dbo.f_parseName(@inFullName varchar(255))
RETURNS 
    @tbl TABLE (lastName varchar(255), firstName varchar(255), middleName varchar(255))
as
BEGIN
-- put your logic here
insert into @tbl(lastName,firstName,middleName)
select substring(@inFullName,0,10),substring(@inFullName,11,10), substring(@inFullName,21,10)

return

end
```

apply the function

```
-- sample data
declare @fullNames table (fullName varchar(255))
insert into @fullNames (fullName) values
('111111111122222222223333333333')
,('AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC')


select 
    fn.fullName
    ,pn.lastName
    ,pn.firstName
    ,pn.middleName
from 
    @fullNames fn
    cross apply dbo.f_parseName(fn.fullName) pn
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work well but for some reason after the 85th row all of the derived columns show NULL? Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out my issue. My stored procedure was making OLE automation calls and I wasn't properly destroying the COM Objects

Answer (score 1):

You could put the results of your stored procedure in a (temporary) table, like this (I added the `FULLNAME` column to provide a join condition, you would have to adapt your stored procedure to do that):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
  FULLNAME NVARCHAR(..)
  ,Last NVARCHAR(..)
  ,First NVARCHAR(..)
  ,MI NVARCHAR(..)
);

INSERT INTO #temp (Last, First, MI)
EXECUTE MySproc;
```

If you want to be able to execute `SELECT Last, First, MI from UserInfo` structurally, you'd have to first add three columns to UserInfo for your name information, and then insert the parsed data that you got from your stored procedure.

**EDIT**

You mention that you use a `SELECT ... INTO ...` to put the data in a new table. I'm guessing that the new table does not have the `FULLNAME` column, and then you would be better off using a table valued function (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639787/249353) suggests). If you keep the `FULLNAME` column however, you can use that to join the temp table with your new table to update the new table as follows:

```
UPDATE NUI
  SET NUI.Last = T.Last, NUI.First = T.First, NUI.MI = T.MI
  FROM NewUserInfo AS NUI
  INNER JOIN #temp AS T ON NUI.FULLNAME = T.FULLNAME;
```

You could use this `UPDATE` method also with another join condition if you do not have the `FULLNAME` column in your new table, but make sure you run a good test beforehand to check if the join holds.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to remove complexity by the way that I was asking my question. I am actually doing a SELECT into to move data from an old table to a new one ( my OP referenced it by mentioning that I was doing an import). The new table has the First middle and last columns already. So if I create the temp table as you suggested, would I then have to Join the temp table to the UserInfo table to get the full list of data?

Comment: Hey @TimN_FL, I added an UPDATE example, but it depends on the availability of the FULLNAME column. You might be better off using a table valued function!

Answer (score 0):

You could add computed columns to table like this:

```
alter table UserInfo
    add firstName as SUBSTRING(fullName, CHARINDEX(',',fullName,0)+2, LEN(fullName)-CHARINDEX(',',fullName,0)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullName),0)-1)
        ,lastName as SUBSTRING(fullName, 0, CHARINDEX(',',fullName,0))
        ,middleInitital as REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fullName),0,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullName),0)))
```

But the best solution would be to do the other way around. Normalize the data with real columns for `firstName`, `lastName` and `middleInitial` and do a computed column for the `fullName`.

The expressions in the code above may need a little more work, as I am sure they can be written more effectivly. I only made them work to show the idea.

After creating the computed columns you may do this:

```
select  firstName
        ,lastName
        ,middleInitital
from UserInfo
```